Supplying power to 2 aaa simulated/fake batteries that are in parallel
I have a device that runs off of 2 aaa batteries that are in parallel. Since they are in parallel, it slightly confuses me and i cannot figure out the proper voltage and current i need to send to the 2 "simulation" aaa batteries that have leads to hook power to.
Would i use one 1.5v power supply source hooked to both batteries, or would i use a 3v power source hooked to both batteries?

Can you share a photo of the "simulation batteries" you're talking about, and how they're connected to or installed in the device they're powering? If they're truly in parallel, and power actually comes from an external power supply, then it's very likely you can simply use just one of them and leave the other one aside.

i dont have any pictures of any. i am going to make the fake battery myself after i have a solid plan and know the proper voltages and current i need.
to try to explain the fake battery better, i guess you could imagine a clear hard plastic tube with contacts on each end that are soldered to positive or negative from the power supply source... like a wall power adapter or buck converter.

Can you share a photo of the battery compartment of the equipment being powered?

let me rephrase the question.
if i want one power supply to supply voltage for 2 aa or aaa batteries, what is the power source voltage? i already know i need ~250mA current, but i just dont know the proper voltage to wire two fake batteries as if each battery was its own independent battery that would work regardless if the other is plugged in or not

It really matters if they're electrically in parallel or series. You don't want to connect external power supplies in parallel --- it could damage one or the other supply or start a fire. You could connect a single supply to both fake batteries but it would gain you nothing over just using one connected fake battery and one inactive fake battery without electrical connections.

i dont have access to my multimeter you see....

Can you share a photo of the battery compartment of the equipment being powered?

if i were to connect two fake batteries to one power source, would the power source need to be 1.5v (which would be wired to 2 batteries) or 3v (to provide 1.5v to each battery).
in my head is the question 3v  to two batteries or 1.5v. i want each of the two batteries to have 1.5v.

1.5 V but if you're wrong and the batteries are in series you could damage the power supply or start a fire.

@james28909 the cell size is AAA, not aaa ... it literally says that on each of the cells

If the batteries are in fact electrically connected in parallel, you can almost certainly simply use one fake battery and ignore the other one, or fill its space with an unpowered/unconnected fake battery to mechanically fill the space.
However its very common for batteries to be installed in a way that mechanically looks "parallel" but is electrically in series. So you should be sure you understand the electrical connection of the batteries before you proceed.

i think that actually it is two seperate circuits. the device is a voice recorder that has on board storage and a micro sd card slot.
give me a little while, i will write up a much better question. because i am not sure of something. each battery may work its own circuit possibly. because i tried to use a good battery in one side and aluminum foil crammed in the other but it didnt work. they cant be in series either because the above scenario didnt work. this leads me to believe that they are possibly working their own circuit? anyway i will write up a better question in a little while.

IF they're in parallel and you replaced one of the batteries with a wad of aluminum foil then you shorted out the first battery so of course it didn't work. If they're in series and you replaced one battery with a wad of aluminum foil then you only had 1.5 V when you should have had 3 V and of course it didn't work.

If the device works with only one AAA battery installed, then the batteries are (almost certainly) connected in parallel, and you would need a single 1.5 volt power supply to replace them.
I think it is more likely that the batteries are connected in series.  In that case, the device will not work with only one battery installed.  If the batteries are connected in series, then you will need a single 3 volt power supply.
A picture of the battery holder would help us determine whether the batteries are connected in series or parallel.

a third possiblity is that they are in series but the center terminal is also used.

there is also a fourth possibility. op had to much coffee and was over thinking, but maybe he will comment and tell everyone how the batteries were indeed in series and not parallel.
